# External Monitor supprt in Dell XPS 13 2015 with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dell

I bought a Dell XPS 13 2015 and everything works well out of the box with Ubuntu 15.04. But I am not able to connect to external monitor through VGA. When I try to connect it never detects the external display. 
Do you have the same issue?

Comment: Which adapter are you using? Maybe it's not supported. Can you use hdmi/dvi instead?

Comment: Any way to switch do a digital interface?

Comment: I am using Dell Display link adapter with VGA.

Comment: Do you understand my question? Can you use HDMI, DVI or DP?

Comment: I didn't have drivers for the Display link VGA adapter. Now I am using the mini display port with VGA and it works fine.